# How to create a cell for row header and column header

Tags: html, css

Please consider this image:

[image]

How I can create yellow cell with diagonal line using CSS and HTML?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried something to achieve this??

Comment: Honestly no, beacause I don't know what should I look for

Answer (score 5):

Use `background-image: linear-gradient()` to  `table th:last-child` and set each text in span and style it as bwlow:

```css
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
table th:last-child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to top left,
    yellow 48%,
    black,
    yellow 52%
  );
}
.col{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th><span class="row">row</span><span class="col">col</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!

Comment: wow ! looking exactly what he wants..

Comment: happy to help really appricate if you mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

```css
td, th { border: 1px solid black; text-align: left; padding: 8px; } 
table { font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; ; } 
table th:last-child { background-image: linear-gradient( to top left, yellow 48%, black, yellow 52% ); } 
.col{ float: right; margin-top: 7px; }
```

```html
<table> 
<tr>  
<th>
<span class="headrow">row</span>
<span class="headcol">col</span>
</th> 
</tr> 
</table>
```